# Converting Offline Revit File to Svf format

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

Hello Autodesk Forge team and dear StackoverFlow members.
Every file format that I view in Autodesk Forge can be exported as svf format in forge and viewed in the viewer. What I want to display in my forge is an "rvt" file format. Is it possible to do this conversion process offline? Because I saw that it can be done for inventor. Can I do this in revit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible with Revit. Inventor API does support export to SVF mainly for [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/overview/) workflows but that is really an exception.

So the conversion of any of the 60+ file formats to SVF must be done using the Forge Model Derivative service, but you're then free to serve the SVF content from wherever you need.